# Vote Up/Down privilege error message hyperlink incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, hyperlinks, error-message

When you upvote or downvote on a site that you don't have enough reputation to vote on, you'll get the error message of "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" or "Vote Down requires 125 reputation". Right now the "Vote Up" and "Vote Down" hyperlinks in those messages point to `$privUrl` instead of the respective privilege pages.

[image: screenshot of ajax response with incorrect url]

Comment: looking fixing..

Comment: @m0sa if only all bugs would have gotten such ultra fast attention... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard If only all bug reports showed the code with the error circled...  ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard if only there would be no bugs... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously this needed more $ to be happy. Fixed in in next build, watch out for version `$versionNumber`.

Comment: Sharp as $ever!